# problem with if statement in instance method

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, instance-methods

HP are supposed to reset to 0 when its 0 or under
But i guess my condition isnt good because it can go under 0.

And i dont understand why when i attack the opponent, it check the wrong opponent.
[pic of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzWf0.png)
Here is the translate of the screenshot :

in the console it say :
Luffy is alive.

in the html it say :
Luffy attacked Naruto and remove him 8HP <- so this code is fine

Luffy HP : 100 <- this is fine because he didnt get attack
Naruto HP : -10  <- this is NOT fine because my instance method checkHealth is suppose to see that he reach 0hp and under.

So checkHealth check the wrong character, it check Luffy the attackers but i want it to check Naruto HP to see if HP are <= 0.

I tried this code and it works but it not very good to do like this bc its not very optimized :

```
    checkHealth (narutoCharacter){ 
        if (narutoCharacter.health <=0){
            narutoCharacter.health = 0;
            popUp.style.display = 'inline';
            popUp.innerText = narutoCharacter.name +' est mort.';
        } else {
            console.log (narutoCharacter.name + ' est en vie');
        }
    }
    checkHealth (luffyCharacter){ 
        if (luffyCharacter.health <=0){
            luffyCharacter.health = 0;
            popUp.style.display = 'inline';
            popUp.innerText = luffyCharacter.name +' est mort.'
        } else {
            console.log (luffyCharacter.name + ' est en vie');
        }
    }
```

Here is my if statement in my instance method :

```
    checkHealth (){ 
        if (this.health <=0){
            this.health = 0;
            popUp.style.display = 'inline';
            popUp.innerText = this.name +' est mort.'
        } else {
            console.log (this.name + ' est en vie');
        }
    }
```

Here is the complete code of my javascript file :

```
class Character {
    constructor (name,type,health,attack,level){
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.health = health;
        this.attack = attack;
        this.level = level;
    }
    levelUp (){
        this.level++;
        popUp.style.display = 'inline';
        popUp.innerText = this.name +' passe au niveau '+ this.level;
    }
    // checkHealth (){ 
    //     if (this.health <=0){
    //         this.health = 0;
    //         popUp.style.display = 'inline';
    //         popUp.innerText = this.name +' est mort.'
    //     } else {
    //         console.log (this.name + ' est en vie');
    //     }
    // }
    checkHealth (narutoCharacter){ 
        if (narutoCharacter.health <=0){
            narutoCharacter.health = 0;
            popUp.style.display = 'inline';
            popUp.innerText = narutoCharacter.name +' est mort.';
        } else {
            console.log (narutoCharacter.name + ' est en vie');
        }
    }
    checkHealth (luffyCharacter){ 
        if (luffyCharacter.health <=0){
            luffyCharacter.health = 0;
            popUp.style.display = 'inline';
            popUp.innerText = luffyCharacter.name +' est mort.'
        } else {
            console.log (luffyCharacter.name + ' est en vie');
        }
    }
    get informations (){
        infoPopUp.innerText = this.name + ' ' + this.type + ' a ' + this.health + ' hp et est au niveau '+ this.level;
        tempMessage.style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
class Ninja extends Character {
    constructor (name, type, health, attack, level){
        super (name, type, health, attack, level)
    }
    attackEnemy (luffyCharacter){
        luffyCharacter.health -= narutoCharacter.attack;
        this.levelUp ();
        popUp.style.display = 'inline';
        popUp.innerText = narutoCharacter.name + ' attaque ' + luffyCharacter.name + ' et lui enlève ' + narutoCharacter.attack + ' PV';
        this.checkHealth (luffyCharacter);
    }
    specialAttack (luffyCharacter){
        (luffyCharacter.health -= narutoCharacter.attack * 3);
        this.levelUp ();
        popUp.style.display = 'inline';
        popUp.innerText = narutoCharacter.name + ' utilise son Rasengan sur ' + luffyCharacter.name + ' et lui enlève ' + narutoCharacter.attack*3 + ' PV';
        this.checkHealth (luffyCharacter);
    }
    heal (){
        narutoCharacter.health += 9;
        popUp.style.display = 'inline';
        popUp.innerText = narutoCharacter.name + ' se soigne.';
    }
}   
class Pirate extends Character {
    constructor (name, type, health, attack, level){
        super (name, type, health, attack, level)
    }
    attackEnemy (narutoCharacter){
        narutoCharacter.health -= luffyCharacter.attack;
        this.levelUp ();
        popUp.style.display = 'inline';
        popUp.innerText = luffyCharacter.name + ' attaque ' + narutoCharacter.name + ' et lui enlève ' + luffyCharacter.attack + ' PV';
        this.checkHealth (narutoCharacter);
    }
    specialAttack (narutoCharacter){
        (narutoCharacter.health -= luffyCharacter.attack * 3);
        this.levelUp ();
        popUp.style.display = 'inline';
        popUp.innerText = luffyCharacter.name + ' utilise Red Hawk sur ' + narutoCharacter.name + ' et lui enlève ' + luffyCharacter.attack*3 + ' PV';
        this.checkHealth (narutoCharacter);
    }
    heal (){
        this.health += 10;
        popUp.style.display = 'inline';
        popUp.innerText = luffyCharacter.name + ' se soigne.';
    }
}
let luffyCharacter = new Ranger ("Luffy", "Ranger", 100, 8, 0);
let narutoCharacter = new Spy ("Naruto", "Spy", 110, 7, 0)

let attackSimpleNaruto = document.getElementById('attack-naruto-simple');
let attackSpecialNaruto = document.getElementById('attack-naruto-special');
let healNaruto = document.getElementById('naruto-heal');

let attackSimpleLuffy = document.getElementById('attack-luffy-simple');
let attackSpecialLuffy = document.getElementById('attack-luffy-special');
let healLuffy = document.getElementById('luffy-heal');

let luffyHp = document.getElementById ('luffy-hp');
let narutoHp = document.getElementById ('naruto-hp');

luffyHp.innerText = '100';
narutoHp.innerText = '110';

let luffyLevel = document.getElementById ('luffy-level');
let narutoLevel = document.getElementById ('naruto-level');

luffyLevel.innerText = '0';
narutoLevel.innerText = '0';

attackSimpleNaruto.addEventListener ('click', () => {
    narutoCharacter.attackEnemy(luffyCharacter);
    luffyHp.innerText = luffyCharacter.health;
    narutoLevel.innerText = narutoCharacter.level;
    luffyCharacter.informations;
})
attackSpecialNaruto.addEventListener ('click', () => {
    narutoCharacter.specialAttack(luffyCharacter);
    luffyHp.innerText = luffyCharacter.health;
    narutoLevel.innerText = narutoCharacter.level;
    luffyCharacter.informations;
})
healNaruto.addEventListener ('click', () => {
    narutoCharacter.heal();
    narutoCharacter.informations;
    narutoLevel.innerText = narutoCharacter.level;
    narutoHp.innerText = narutoCharacter.health;
})

attackSpecialLuffy.addEventListener ('click', () => {
    luffyCharacter.specialAttack(narutoCharacter);
    narutoHp.innerText = narutoCharacter.health;
    luffyLevel.innerText = luffyCharacter.level;
    narutoCharacter.informations;
})
healLuffy.addEventListener ('click', () => {
    luffyCharacter.heal();
    luffyHp.innerText = luffyCharacter.health;
    luffyLevel.innerText = luffyCharacter.level;
    luffyCharacter.informations;
})
attackSimpleLuffy.addEventListener ('click', () => {
    luffyCharacter.attackEnemy(narutoCharacter);
    narutoHp.innerText = narutoCharacter.health;
    luffyLevel.innerText = luffyCharacter.level;
    narutoCharacter.informations;
})
```

Thanks for trying to help me !

Comment: class spy : where is naruto character from,
class ranger: where is luffy character from

Comment: classes spy and ranger are totally overflowing. You need class for game logic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like that

```
class Character {
constructor (name,type,health,attack,level){
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.health = health;
    this.attack = attack;
    this.level = level;
}
levelUp (){
    this.level++;
    popUp.style.display = 'inline';
    popUp.innerText = this.name +' passe au niveau '+ this.level;
}
checkHealth (){ 
    if (this.health <=0){
        this.health = 0;
        popUp.style.display = 'inline';
        popUp.innerText = this.name +' est mort.'
    } else {
        console.log ('Toto');
    }
}
get informations (){
    infoPopUp.innerText = this.name + ' ' + this.type + ' a ' + this.health 
+ ' hp et est au niveau '+ this.level;
         tempMessage.style.display = 'inline';
    }
}

class Game{
    attack(source, target){
        target.health -= source.attack; 
        return target.checkHealth()
    }
}

var game = new Game();
var luffy = new Character('Luffi','spy',100, 5, 3);
var naruto = new Character('Naruto','ranger',120, 2, 5);

game.attack(naruto, luffy);
```

or you make Attack member of Charakter, then you have somethink like this:

```
class Character {
    ....
    checkHealth (){ 
        if (this.health <=0){
            this.health = 0;
            popUp.style.display = 'inline';
            popUp.innerText = this.name +' est mort.'
        } else {
            console.log ('Toto');
        }
    }
   .....

   Attacke(target){
    target.health -= this.attack; 
    return target.checkHealth()
   }
}

luffi.Attack(naruto)
```

Comment: If i want to put this : 
`
class Game{
    attack(source, target){
        target.health -= source.attack; 
        return target.checkHealth()
    }
} `

in a instance method, where should i insert the code ? In class Character or 2 in each class Spy & Ranger ?

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: @EliasP the question is not entirely correct. You don't have to insert it anywhere. They describe classes Character, Game etc. And then they have to organize game loops...

Comment: If i add 
`   Attacke(target){
    target.health -= this.attack; 
    return target.checkHealth()
   }
} `
to Character Class, i need to remove my attackEnemy from Spy & Ranger ?

Comment: You need to remove classes Spy and Ranger :) O.. you have change your code :) yes.. yu need remove attackAnamy

Answer (score 0):

```
luffyCharacter.attackEnemy(narutoCharacter);
```

when luffy(`Ranger`) attacks naruto, in `Ranger.attackEnemy` you, deal damage to naruto, but you check luffyCharacter health, why?

Comment: The code where Luffy attack Naruto is right here :   
 `attackEnemy (narutoCharacter){
        narutoCharacter.health -= luffyCharacter.attack;
        this.levelUp ();
        popUp.style.display = 'inline';
        popUp.innerText = luffyCharacter.name + ' attaque ' + narutoCharacter.name + ' et lui 
        enlève ' + luffyCharacter.attack + ' PV';
        this.checkHealth (narutoCharacter);
   } `
i check naruto hp.

Thanks for trying @birdspider

Comment: @EliasP, your original code changed, `this.checkHealth (narutoCharacter)` is NOT how you check naruto hp.

Comment: Ok so how can i check naruto hp ? if you have a solution it will be better than adding code with new class game^^

Thanks for your answer